# Properties file not loading and updating for relative path but working fine for absolute path

Tags: java

I am trying to access a properties file from the `src/main/resources` folder but when I try to load the file using a relative path it is not getting updated. But it is working fine for an absolute path.

I need the dynamic web project to work across all platforms.

```
public static void loadUsers() {

  try(
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\SohamGuha\\Documents\\work-coding\\work-coding\\src\\main\\resources\\users.properties")) {
    // write code to load all the users from the property file
    // FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("classpath:users.properties");

    users.load(in);
    System.out.println(users);
    in.close();

  }
  catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: Can you paste your classpath?

Comment: FileInputStream  takes location of the file so your path is something like this 
`new FileInputStream("src\main\resources\users.properties")`

Comment: I have tried with classpath. Properties file not getting updated. This is a dynamic web project i am trying to load the properties file and make some changes in it taking in form-input values.

Comment: Have you tried using classloader.getResource()?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using Spring, at least that is what the tags at the bottom say. Secondly `C:\\Users\\SohamGuha\\Documents\\work-coding\\work-coding\\src\\main\\resources\\users.properties` is the root of your classpath. Instead of loading a `File` use the [Spring resource abstraction](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#resources).

As this is part of the classpath you can simply use the [`ClassPathResource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#resources-implementations-classpathresource) to obtain a proper `InputStream`. This will work regardless of which environment you are in.

```
try( InputStream in = new ClassPathResource("users.properties").getInputStream()) {
    //write code to load all the users from the property file
    //FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("classpath:users.properties");
    users.load(in);
    System.out.println(users);
} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**NOTE:** you are already using a try with resources so  you don't need to close the `InputStream` that is already handled for you.

Changing things inside your application simply won't work, as this would mean you could change resources (read classes) in your jar which would be quite a security risk! If you want something to be changable you will have to make it a file outside of the classpath and directly on the file-system.

Comment: What about for OutputStream ?

Comment: As stated in my answer you cannot change things in a classpath resource. This would only be possible with a regular file resource and has to be pointing to a resource outside the classpath. Then you can also obtain an `OutputStream` if the resource is a [`WriteableResource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/WritableResource.html).

Comment: So we cannot update a properties  file which is in classpath?

Comment: You cannot write to things inside your jar/war as that would mean external resources could also modify your class files, now tha tis something you probably don't want to happen!.

Answer (score 0):

Try  the following code

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class LoadUsers {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

```
try(FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/users.properties")){
    Properties users=new Properties();
     users.load(fis);
     System.out.println(users);
    }catch(IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}